# finding streamline and plotting it on a graph

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the streamlines for the following flow:
[image: flow equation].

We are plotting our stagnation points with a sparatrix line but somehow the streamline just goes over it...
We cannot use the stream function. Any idea what is wrong?

Somehow the plot is not plotting correctly...here is my matlab code:

```
%% constant parameters
a=1;
U=100;
T=3*pi*a*U;

%% plot the stagnation points
syms z 
k=100./z^2 - 1i*3./(2*z) - 100==0;    %diff(w)==0
stagpoint=solve(k,z);                 %get the points
plot(stagpoint,'MarkerFaceColor','g');

%% plot the the sparatrix line
[x,y]=meshgrid([-7:0.1:7],[-2:0.1:2]);
z=x+1i*y;
w1=-100*(z+1./z)-1i*log(z).*3*pi*100./(2*pi);
psi=imag(w1);
limit=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
x((limit<0.99))=NaN;
y((limit<0.99))=NaN;

contour(x,y,psi,'k');
xlabel('Re');
ylabel('Im');
title('streamline for question4(a)');


axis([-5 5 -5 5])
daspect([1 1 1]);
hold on

%% plot streamline

RK4_4A(z);

%% plot the surface of the cylinder
angle=[0:0.1:360];
x=cosd(angle);          %x component of the cylinder
y=sind(angle);          %y component of the cylinder
plot(x,y);
hold on
fill(x,y,'r');
```

Here is the function we use for the 4th Order Runge-Kutta Method:

```
function RK4_4A(zn)

h=0.001;
x=5;
y=[-5:0.5:5];
zn=x+1i*y;

for j=1:length(y)
    z(1)=zn(j);
     t=0:h:2;
for i=1:length(t)-1

    k1 = ffunc(z(i));
    k2 = ffunc(z(i)+h/2*k1);
    k3 = ffunc(z(i)+h/2*k2);
    k4 = ffunc(z(i)+h*k3);

    z(i+1) = z(i) + h*(1/6*k1+1/3*k2...
        +1/3*k3+1/6*k4);
end

 plot(real(z),imag(z),'b');

    hold on

end

function s=ffunc(z)
s = 100./z^2 - 1i*3./(2*z) - 100;
s=conj(s);

end

end
```

Comment: In `function RK4_4A(zn)` you receive data `zn` but a bit later you replace `zn` by `x+1i*y`. Why do you do this?